# maven fails when creating archetype

Tags: java, maven, velocity

I tried to creat a project in IntelliJ IDEA using Maven quickstart archetype but it allways failed:

```
[ERROR] ResourceManager.getResource() parse exception

[ERROR] org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Lexical error,   Encountered: "\ufffd" (65533), after : "" at archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/mybootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot[line 16, column 21]
```

Here is the full output:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeGenerationFailure: Error merging velocity templates: Lexical error,   Encountered: "\ufffd" (65533), after : "" at archetype-resources/src/main/webapp/mybootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot[line 16, column 21] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] Maven execution terminated abnormally (exit code 1)
```

Comment: You might have a broken local repository. Close intelliJ, delete the relevant parts (containing the archetypes) and try again.

Comment: Get the same thing. I also deleted the local repo and still nothing.